# cmake file(RELATIVE_PATH ...) for files that cannot be relative

Tags: windows, cmake

Under Windows, it's possible to have directories that cannot be formed relative to one another, because they exist on different drives. Making a minimal CMake script, that attempts this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
set(FILEA "C:/Directory/MyFile")
set(FILEB "E:/AnotherDirectory/AnotherFile")
file(RELATIVE_PATH relativePath ${FILEA} ${FILEB})
message("relativePath = ${relativePath}")
```

Produces (running `cmake .`):

```
...
relativePath = E:/AnotherDirectory/AnotherFile
...
```

This is obviously not correct. Is there any way to determine that the call to `file(RELATIVE_PATH ...)` has "failed"?

Comment: Hardcoding full paths must be the wrong way of doing things. Are You familiar with `find_*()` group of CMake functions? More on topic on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25417938/1150918)

Comment: @Kamiccolo it's a minimal example of what is happening in my actual script, which doesn't hardcode things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just looked at CMake's source code - in this case [`SystemTools::RelativePath()`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/kwsys/SystemTools.cxx#L3457) - and it just returns the "remote" path by design if the drive letters on Windows are not the same:

> ```
> // If there is nothing in common at all then just return the full
> // path.  This is the case only on windows when the paths have
> // different drive letters.  On unix two full paths always at least
> // have the root "/" in common so we will return a relative path
> // that passes through the root directory.
> if (sameCount == 0) {
>   return remote;
> }
> ```

Since in your case there is no error thrown, you can just do something like compare the input with the result and throw the error yourself:

```
if (NOT FILEA STREQUAL FILEB AND FILEB STREQUAL relativePath)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "... your text goes here ...")
endif()
```

Comment: if `(IS_ABSOLUTE relativePath)` should just work as well :) But again, it's tied to the undocumented behavior. Having in mind that on some older CMake versions it used to screw up the path instead of returning mentioned "full path".

Comment: @Kamiccolo Yeah, thanks. Yours is much more straight forward :-) One way would also be to reverse check the result with something like `get_filename_component(absolutePath "${FILEA}/${relativePath}" ABSOLUTE)` and then do a `if (absolutePath STREQUAL FILEB)` check.